# Bind C Integer to Lua global variable

Tags: c, lua

In C I want to call a lua function myFunction() that uses a global variable x. I want to be able to register a c (integer) variable directly as this global variable x.

Something along the lines:

## demo.lua:

```
function myFunction()
  return x + 3
end
```

## demo.c:

```
int x = 0;
lua_bindglob(L, "x", &x);

for (x = 0; x < 100; ++x)
{
  lua_getglobal(L, "myFunction");

  // here I call the function and it should evaluate
  // to the current value of x (in c)
  lua_pcall(L, 0, 1, 0);      
  int result = lua_tonumber(L, -1);  

  lua_pop(L, 1);
}
```

I know that I can modify lua global variables by this:

```
lua_pushnumber(L, 3);
lua_setglobal(L, "x");
```

But I need to have a more direct/faster way of doing this. I got a hint that LUA ligthuserdata might help here but I couldn't find any examples for plain variables.

EDIT:
Since I get the expressions from a benchmark I do not want to alter them:
See examples [here](https://github.com/ArashPartow/math-parser-benchmark-project/blob/master/bench_expr_complete.txt):

Comment: I don't know that there is a way to directly do what you want to do. I ran into the same problem a few months ago and ended up settling for a table/userdata with a metatable that had  the `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods defined as accessor functions

Comment: My guess is -- an integer in Lua is an object, thus C code should be able to see and modify it's internal repsentation (may not map to a 32-bit int). If you ever change the value in Lua, new value will have a new address. A better approach would be to access C's `int` via `FFI` --- the foreign function interface. That requires, at least, that C code exports given data item as a symbol. Please follow http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you're going to be able to get is the ability to create a piece of userdata (regular, not light) that has a `__call` metamethod that will get/set the C value for you.

So your function would look like:

```
function myFunction()
  return x() + 3
end
```

It could also have operator metamethods defined so that things like `x + 3` could work. But there's no way for a naked `x` to resolve to the value you want.

Setting the value would look like:

```
x(3)
```

There's no way to make something like `x = 3` work the way you want it to. This will always overwrite the value in question.

Using `__newindex` and `__index` metamethods wouldn't work because you want the variable to be *global*.

Alternatively, you could use LuaJIT and its FFI interface.

Comment: Even with the LuaJIT FFI, I think that (global) key assignment will rebind the variable.

Comment: I ended up with LuaJIT as the fastest way. But still too slow to beat exprTK.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a few C variables that you want to access from Lua, you can set a metatable with `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods on the globals table. When a non-existent global variable is accessed (get or set), those metamethods are called, and you have to figure out what to do by looking at the second parameter to those metamethods (the variable name).

Sample code for a module that exports a single variable:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>


static int x = 0;


static int myvar_index( lua_State* L ) {
  char const* key = lua_tostring( L, 2 );
  if( key != NULL && strcmp( key, "x" ) == 0 )
    lua_pushinteger( L, x );
  else
    lua_pushnil( L );
  return 1;
}


static int myvar_newindex( lua_State* L ) {
  char const* key = lua_tostring( L, 2 );
  if( key != NULL && strcmp( key, "x" ) == 0 ) {
    lua_Integer i = luaL_checkinteger( L, 3 );
    if( i > INT_MAX || i < INT_MIN )
      luaL_error( L, "variable value out of range" );
    x = i;
  } else
    lua_rawset( L, 1 );
  return 0;
}


int luaopen_myvar( lua_State* L ) {
  luaL_Reg const metamethods[] = {
    { "__index", myvar_index },
    { "__newindex", myvar_newindex },
    { NULL, NULL }
  };
#if LUA_VERSION_NUM < 502
  lua_pushvalue( L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX );
  lua_newtable( L );
  luaL_register( L, NULL, metamethods );
#else
  lua_pushglobaltable( L );
  luaL_newlib( L, metamethods );
#endif
  lua_setmetatable( L, -2 );
  return 0;
}
```

The more C variables you export, the more complicated the metamethod implementations get, and you are probably better off using one of the other suggested approaches.

Also note that the globals table is a shared resource, so you have to avoid/handle conflicts with other code that modifies its metatable. (I.e. reusable modules simply shouldn't modify shared resources -- but I guess the same applies to global variables in C ...)

Comment: Will this affect the default behavior for accessing globals in an undesirable way?

Comment: It will affect the behavior for accessing *undefined* globals. Most globals you work with have non-nil values. Those aren't affected at all. Accessing nil-valued globals will incur an extra metamethod call.